# Https locally on Linux with Play Framework

Tags: linux, scala, ubuntu, ssl, playframework

I have a Play scala application which is on localhost. I want to add SSL certificate (https) to it and test it locally. I found some articles but they all were about Apache.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There's official documentation for Play 2.2 how to do this: [Configuring Https](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps)

I'd rather use ngingx proxy to provide ssl for play on their official [site](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) there are plenty of examples and tutorials

Comment: So I can use https with Play built-in server? No need to setup other one?